# ImportPhotos Plugin error - no new photos were added

Tags: qgis-plugins, photos, geotag

I have 7 .JPG photos that I'm trying to import so that when I identify features, a photo will pop up on the feature that I click. I've been trying to use the ImportPhotos Plugin, but every time I select the folder with the .JPG photos, I get the error "No new photos were added."

Has anyone successfully used the ImportPhotos plugin or been able to put geotagged photos onto their map so that the photos pop up when you identify features? If so, could you please explain the process? Haven't been able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and discovered that I needed to add an output file name as well as the input.  Addiing a name without a valid extension resulted in no pictures added but adding the .json extensin to the name pictures.json worked.

Comment: Including a screenshot showing how and where you added the extension would geatly improve your answer.